# Button from another form doesn't work in IE8 , IE10?

Tags: html, forms, button, internet-explorer-8

I want to use buttons inside a form to submit another form using attribute 'form'. It works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but it doesn't work in IE10, and IE8.

I also need to use attribute 'formaction' of button. Although it works in IE10 but it doens't work in IE8.

I also need to get $_POST['outside'] and $_POST['export'] when the related button is clicked.

Here are the codes. Could you experts please provide a guidance? Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<!--meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="image/png;" />
<title>US Mian</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="http://www.apple.com" method="post"  name="form1"  id="form1" style="border:1px solid red; margin:30px;" >
   <label> Last Name: </label>
   <input type="text" name="lastname" value="" /><br>
   <button  type="submit"   name="inside"  form="form1" onclick=""> button_inside - Go to Apple</button>
</form>


<h2> The following two buttons do not work in IE8. </h2>
<form action="http://www.cnn.com" method="post"  name="form2"  id="form1" style="border:1px solid red; margin:30px;" >
   <button type="submit"   name="outside"  form="form1" onclick=""> button_otherform - Go to Apple</button><br>
   <button  type="submit"   name="export" formaction="http://www.yahoo.com" fromtarget="export_dummy_iframe2" />button-using-formaction: Go to Yahoo</button>
</form>       

<iframe style="display:none;" name="export_dummy_iframe2">  </iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `form`, `formaction` and `formaction` attributes are HTML5 attributes and are *only* supported in IE 10+.  Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button  You will probably need to use JavaScript to emulate this behavior.

Comment: I am a new in Javascript. Any guidance on the Javascript emulation please.

Comment: You'd need to add event handlers to each of the buttons, and then trigger the correct form's submit handler.  Something like that.